# Automate Hyperlink Creations

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to automate hyperlink creations on my GSheet.

Here's my script:

```
 function ticketURLGenerator() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var range = sheet.getRange("C2:C");
  var ticketID = range.getValue();
  Logger.log(ticketID);
  
  for(i = 0; i < ticketID.length; i++){
    if(ticketID.length === 0){
      ticketID.setValue('')
    } else if(ticketID.length > 4){
    ticketID.setValue('=HYPERLINK' + '("https://mylink.com/'+ticketID+'";'+ticketID+')');
    }
  }  
}
```

It does nothing but when I change `ticketID.setValue` by `sheet.getRange("C2:C").setValue` it put the whole range in the url. We can see with `Logger.log(ticketID)` that the whole range is selected.

So according to this result, i'm missing how to get the value of each cell individualy in the range and then check if they are long enought to create an individual url. Do I need to use something like range[i] somewhere? I'm lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values from the cells "C2:C".
- When the length of value is more than 4, you want to create a formula of `HYPERLINK`.
- When the length of value is less than 4, you don't want to put the formula.
- You want to put the formulas to the cells "C2:C".

#### Modification points:

- When `range` of `var range = sheet.getRange("C2:C")` is used, the value of `var ticketID = range.getValue()` is the value of cell "C2". When you want to retrieve values from the cells "C2:C", please use `getValues` instead of `getValue`.

  - In this case, the retrieved value is 2 dimensional array.
- When `range.getValue()` is the string value, `ticketID` of `var ticketID = range.getValue()` is also the string. So I think that when `ticketID.setValue('##')` is run, an error occurs.
- In your script, `setValue` is used in a loop. In this case, the process cost will become high.
- And, when `sheet.getRange("C2:C" + sheet.getLastRow())` is used instead of `sheet.getRange("C2:C")`, the process cost will become low a little.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function ticketURLGenerator() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var range = sheet.getRange("C2:C" + sheet.getLastRow());
  var ticketIDs = range.getValues();
  var values = ticketIDs.map(([c]) => [c.toString().length > 4 ? `=HYPERLINK("https://mylink.com/${c}";"${c}")` : c]);
  range.setValues(values);
}
```

- In this modification, the values are retrieved from the cells of `"C2:C" + sheet.getLastRow()`, and an array including the formulas and values is created, and then, the array is put to the cells.
- And I used the template literal for creating the formula.

#### Note:

- In this case, please use this script with enabling V8 runtime.

#### References:

- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow())
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: @Marios Oh! It's almost the same!

Comment: I only missed the iternary operation. I will vote up your answer since it has the full explanation and the answer is more clear :)

Comment: @Marios Thank you. I think that your proposal answer can also resolve OP's issue.

Comment: Sure, I hope he accepts your answer which is more informative.

Comment: Hello guys ! Thank you for your responses. Marios 's solution was easier to understand since it's a more "common" look (from a beginner eye). But thank you Tanaike for very well explaining your answer ! I understood my errors, it will helps me to get a better approach for my future scripts! I tested your solutions and they are both working. So thank you again for your time.

Comment: @Veermo Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to apply the `HYPERLINK` operation to the tickets that their length is more than 4. To achieve that, you can use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over all the elements in your list.

### Solution:

```
function ticketURLGenerator() { 

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  const ticketR = sheet.getRange("C2:C"+sheet.getLastRow());
  const ticketIDs = ticketR.getDisplayValues().flat();
  const hLinks = ticketIDs.map(ti=>{ 
    if(ti.length>4) { 
    return [`=HYPERLINK("https://mylink.com/${ti}"; ${ti})`]}
    else {return [ti]}
})     
 ticketR.setValues(hLinks);
}
```